# jQuery .filter() dont work

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a html page that contain a form with id "frmCmt", i want to just show this form in other document, i using jQuery .filter() but now work and show full page.

my jQuery code:

```
function showCommentForm(postID){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
cache: true, 
url: "http://mysite.com/post/comment/"+postID,
success:(function(msg){
$("#commentContainer"+postID).html(msg).filter("#frmCmt") ;
return false;
})});
```

please help.

Comment: My problem is still not resolved, I am waiting for your solutions. i get this error when using one of codes below! Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <html><head>... jquery.min.js:4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will not work for three reasons:

1. You are injecting everything in `msg` into your element as HTML; `.filter` only runs *after* this has happened, so it cannot possibly work.
2. `.filter` filters items from the matched set of a jQuery object, but tou are not using the result of `.filter` to do anything so again it would not work.
3. The matched set in this case does not include any `#frmCmt` element so `.filter` will evaluate to an "empty" jQuery instance; even if that were somehow used the results would not be what you expected.

Change the code to

```
var html = $(msg).find("#frmCmt").html();
$("#commentContainer"+postID).html(html);
```

This code creates a jQuery object from the contents of `msg` and zeroes in on the required element with `.find` before inserting it into the DOM.

Comment: i get this error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <html><head>... jquery.min.js:4

Comment: @IRonMAN: That's not helpful at all, and it is totally unclear (but very troubling) why you would be evaluating HTML as JS code. You need to do some debugging -- what code causes the error? What's the input to that code?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `find()` instead of .filter() here, filter will work only if the given element is a top level element in `msg`

One way to fix it could be

```
$(msg).find('#frmCmt').appendTo($("#commentContainer"+postID).empty())
```

Or you can use the .load() function

```
$("#commentContainer"+postID).load("http://mysite.com/post/comment/"+postID + ' #frmCmt')
```

Comment: Hey Arun , you just edited my answer , seems like by mistake :)

Comment: @Cherniv sorry, yes it was a mistake

Comment: It is because of order "shuffling"